# SMB share authentication not working

Tags: linux, debian, samba, smb

i have problem with SMB share. I have 4 directories for users and one collective dir. I make accounts for users (Linux accounts and smb accounts). I could see directories in Nautilius but can't log in. When I make share for guests it works like a charm.

My smb.conf:

```
[global]
; General server settings
netbios name = Microserver
server string =
workgroup = WORKGROUP
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_$

passdb backend = tdbsam
security = user
encrypt passwords = true
name resolve order = hosts wins bcast
interfaces = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.10/24
bind interfaces only = yes
wins support = yes

printing = CUPS
printcap name = CUPS

syslog = 1
syslog only = yes

[foo1]
    path = /smb/foo1
    read only = no
    writable = yes
    browseable = yes
    valid users = foo1
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755

[foo2]
    path = /smb/foo2
    read only = no
    writable = yes
    browseable = yes
    valid users = foo2
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755

...

[colective]
    read only = no
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    path = /smb/colective
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
```

OS: Debian 8.1.0